# Interpretation of Rigveda verse 1.164.31 according to Advaita Vedanta

Tags: krishna, rig-veda, brahman, gaudiya-vaishnavism, interpretation

While looking up for verses on the Rigveda Samhita, I stumbled upon the verse 1.164.31 on a [blog](https://nitaigaurangablog.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/ekam-sad-vipra-bahudha-vadanti-the-real-meaning/) which says this:

> **अप॑श्यं गो॒पामनि॑पद्यमान॒मा च॒ परा॑ च प॒थिभि॒श्चर॑न्तम् । स स॒ध्रीची॒: स विषू॑ची॒र्वसा॑न॒ आ व॑रीवर्ति॒ भुव॑नेष्व॒न्तः ॥**
>
> *I saw a cowherd. He never falls from his position; sometimes he is near, and sometimes far, wandering on various paths. He is a friend, decorated with a variety of clothes. He comes again and again to the material world.*

Understanding that it's written from a Gaudiya Vaishnava POV, I'd like to know how would advaitins interpret this verse. The translation of this verse on Wisdomlib is given as:

> *“I have beheld the unwearied protector of the universe, the sun, travelling upwards, the downwards by various paths; invested with aggregative and diffusive radiance, he revolves in the midst of the regions.”*

Yet, it would be great if someone can explain this in a neutral way.

Comment: Read Sayana's commentary

Comment: @Anubrata: Any legit source where I can get to read it?